# Python matrix: need to show where values are equal to vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have this vector: `[-3,0,2,4,7,10,12]`

and this matrix:

```
[[ 7.   7.   4. ]
 [12.  10.  10. ]
 [-3.   7.   2. ]
 [10.   8.  12. ]
 [ nan  7.   nan]
 [ 7.   7.  10. ]
 [ 4.5  nan  2. ]
 [ 2.  12.   4. ]]
```

I have to show where in the matrix the the values are equal to in the vector. So it would show me which row and column 8 and 4.5 are e.g.

Any quick way to do this?

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: Somehow to show the places like " row x, column y"

Comment: have you tried `np.where()`?

Comment: No, but does it not only work with vectors?

Comment: np.where(matrixGrades==-3 & matrixGrades==0 & matrixGrades==2 & matrixGrades==4 & matrixGrades==7 & matrixGrades==10 matrixGrades==& matrixGrades==12)
Like this?

Comment: can you show your expected output example?

Comment: an expected result example will help us a lot to understand what it is exactly you're looking for.
Do you want a matrix that only shows where the values are equal to some value in the 2d array? or do you want to iterate over the matrix and mark where the values are not in the array and mark their location... please give us a more through explanation of the output you're looking for :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's a small array like in your example, a simple iteration over the rows and columns would do... like so:

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([-3, 0, 2, 4, 7, 10, 12])
m = np.array([[ 7. ,  7. ,  4. ],
              [12. , 10. , 10. ],
              [-3. ,  7. ,  2. ],
              [10. ,  8. , 12. ],
              [ np.NaN,  7. ,  np.NaN],
              [ 7. ,  7. , 10. ],
              [ 4.5,  np.NaN,  2. ],
              [ 2. , 12. ,  4. ]])

#Iterations starts here
index_list = []
for i in range(m.shape[0]):
    for j in range(m.shape[1]):
        if m[i][j] not in v:
            index_list.append((i,j))
```

The output of this code (if you print `index_list`) is:

```
[(3, 1), (4, 0), (4, 2), (6, 0), (6, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to compare each value with the whole 2d array, and then get indexes using [numpy.argwhere](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```py
import numpy as np

v = np.array([-3, 0, 2, 4, 7, 10, 12])

m = np.array([[ 7. ,  7. ,  4. ],
              [12. , 10. , 10. ],
              [-3. ,  7. ,  2. ],
              [10. ,  8. , 12. ],
              [ nan,  7. ,  nan],
              [ 7. ,  7. , 10. ],
              [ 4.5,  nan,  2. ],
              [ 2. , 12. ,  4. ]]))

t = m[None,...] == v[:,None,None]

np.argwhere(t)
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 6, 2],
       [2, 7, 0],
       [3, 0, 2],
       [3, 7, 2],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 1],
       [4, 2, 1],
       [4, 4, 1],
       [4, 5, 0],
       [4, 5, 1],
       [5, 1, 1],
       [5, 1, 2],
       [5, 3, 0],
       [5, 5, 2],
       [6, 1, 0],
       [6, 3, 2],
       [6, 7, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Let's use the first row `[0, 2, 0]` of the result to understand what represents:

- The first column is the index of the value in `v` that we are looking at, i.e. `v[0] = -3`.
- The second and third column are the indexes in which the value in `m` is equal to such value in `v`, i.e. `m[2,0] = -3`.

If in the first column a index doesn't appear it means that such value is not present in `m` (e.g. 0 is not in `m`) while if a index appears multiple times it means that such value is present more than once in `m` (e.g. the value `v[2] = 2`).